# Can I convert from swf (or fla or svg or snap or sprite.js) to bodymovin

Tags: bodymovin

I have a bunch of animated vector graphic files that I would like to convert to bodymovin (I assume I would need to convert them into after effects first and use the bodymovin extension).

I animated files in swf, fla, svg (using the animate element inside the svg), snap and sprite.js html5 formats.  I need to preserve the animations (recreating them is not an option)

Is this possible?  Any ideas?

I have imported one of my animated swfs directly into after effects and exported to an mp4 but it won't export to bodymovin (I think swf and the vector graphics are very different)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You should get Bodymovin plugin for Adobe Animate CC. Have a look here: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/1604